# Setting custom salt string in MessageDigestPasswordEncoder in spring security 5

Tags: hash, encoding, spring-security, md5, salt

I have my passwords stored in the DB as MD5 hashes for which I had used my custom salt. Now while changing the password I have to convert the "Old Password" to appropriate MD5 hash(using my custom hash) and check if the hash stored in the DB and this generated hash matches. This worked fine until I upgraded spring security to version 5. In new version I am trying to use org.springframework.security.crypto.password.MessageDigestPasswordEncoder which uses its custom salt to generate the MD5 hash. I don't see a way to add custom salt so that the hash matches with the stored hash. What should I do? Is there some alternative class I can use to convert the password to MD5 hash? 
Any help would be appreciated.